# Print NSMutableArray into UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my application I have a tableview with a barbuttonitem. When I press the barbuttonitem, I see an alertcontroller that allows me to enter data. Then later, save these data within a NSMutableArray and my purpose is to print one of these data within the cells of a tableview. The problem is that the data acquisition is correct, but the tableview remains empty. I do not understand why, it seems all right!

Class: FeedInfo

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FeedInfo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *feedURL;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *feedTitle;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *feedCategory;
@end
```

And then I have a barbuttonitem inside a tableview. When I click on this button, I open a controller alert that allows me to enter 3 fields: url, feed, category.

I have declared `@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *feedArray;`

I then insert these dates into the NSMutableArray.

```
- (IBAction)inserFeed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"Feed RSS: info?"
                                                                              message: @""
                                                                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Feed URL";
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    }];

    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Feed Title";
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    }];

    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Feed category";
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    }];

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        NSArray * textfields = alertController.textFields;

        UITextField * urlfield = textfields[0];
        UITextField * titlefield = textfields[1];
        UITextField * categoryfield = textfields[2];

        FeedInfo *newFeed = [[FeedInfo alloc] init];
        newFeed.feedURL = urlfield.text;
        newFeed.feedTitle = titlefield.text;
        newFeed.feedCategory = categoryfield.text;


        [self.feedArray addObject:newFeed];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }]];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Everything works here. The problem is printing one of these fields within a cell of my tableview.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    FeedInfo *feedToShow = [self.feedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = feedToShow.feedTitle;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: did you assign the `TableViewDatasource` protocol to your controller? Did you override `numberOfRowsInSection `?

Comment: @dirtydanee i entered `self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;`  in viewDidLoad.  As for the methods, I wrote `-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}`

Comment: and `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.feedArray.count;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your cell creation. Your `cell` object is `nil`

Use the following code to get the cell object.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

> `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath`  : newer dequeue method guarantees a cell is returned and resized properly, assuming identifier is registered

If you didn't set the `cell identifier` on the `xib/storyboard` then 
You must call `registerClass` or `registerNib` in order to be able to use the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method.

**Update :**

Datasource array is not allocated. Allocate `feedArray` inside the `viewDidLoad()`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad]; 
   self.feedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

Comment: Equal result, empty tableview :(

Comment: Have you added cell identifier on xib/storyboard?

Comment: yep, my cell identifier is 'cell'

Comment: @Taprolano What is your cell class? And can you put the break point and check the cell object is `nil` or not

Comment: i I inserted this check right after the cell was created `if (cell == nil)
    {
         NSLog(@"error");
    }` And nothing is printed. So I suppose the cell is not nil

Comment: Add this code inside `viewDidLoad` `[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"class"];`

Comment: Have you allocated `feedArray` object

Comment: xcode: **Unknown receiver 'tableView'; did you mean 'UITableView'?** wtf?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149325/discussion-between-subramanian-and-taprolano).

Comment: @Taprolano Updated the answer. Your `feedArray` was not allocated. Due to that your datas are not added

Comment: This answer should be updated to include the fact that you must also call `registerClass` or `registerNib` in order to be able to use the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks.. Updated the answer